# Does anything happen in the Agent Carter series that impacts/references anything in the MCU?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, agent-carter

Thanks to Netflix's glitch a few weeks back, I thought the first season of [*Agent Carter* (2015-16)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3475734/) was only 3 episodes long, and Season 2 skipped episodes.

Is it really necessary to go back and re-watch it all now that Netflix has fixed this issue?  From what I watched, there really wasn't much that was later relevant in, or referenced, the MCU, except for Howard Stark finally getting his hover car to work (which was originally shown in [*Captain America: The First Avenger* (2011)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0458339/)).

Comment: Why not watch it for the enjoyment of its own self? Connections with the MCU aren't really important in that respect.

Comment: @Paulie_D - Well, what I saw I wouldn't consider to be "must see TV".  So I was just going to move on to the next show rather than go back and re-watch it.  I was just curious if anything pops up that fills in gaps from the MCU movies.

Comment: The show itself references a lot of characters (Peggy Carter, Howard Stark, the Howling Commandos, Ivan Vanko, Arnim Zola etc.) and organizations (SSR, SHIELD, Red Room) from the MCU proper. It would take a while to compile a full list. It doesn't have a lot of impact on other movies, although some characters from the show later appear in other MCU properties.

Comment: For what it's worth, the IMDB ratings for individual episodes show a [marked increase in quality for the second half of Season 1.](https://www.ratingraph.com/tv-shows/agent-carter-ratings-51012/)

Answer (score 1):

Whilst no actions from the series cause any events to happen in the MCU timeline, it is quite a good series to watch and provides useful background information about both Captain America and Tony Stark (mostly his family history).

Comment: I loved Agent Carter! Wish they would bring it back!!!!!